# Solving an equation about water filling algorithm.

Tags: algorithms

Recently, I am reading a document about the water filling algorithm. I encounter an equation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^r \left[ \mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i} \right]_+ = 1,\tag{1}$$
where $r$ is a positive integer, $\mu$ is the variable of the equation, $\rho$ and $\lambda_i$ are positive constant, and the $+$ in the subscript is defined as
$$x_+=\begin{cases}
x, & x \geq 0 \\
0, & x < 0.
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$
The document then tells me the solution is
$$\mu=\frac{1}{r} \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i=1}^r \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \right].\tag{3}$$
My question is: How to solve the equation (1) to get the solution in (3)?

---

Here is my try:
Let $S$ be a subset of $\{1, 2, ..., r\}$ such that if $i \in S$, then
$$\mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i} \geq 0.$$
Then we have
$$\sum_{i \in S} \left( \mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i} \right) = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow |S| \mu - \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i \in S} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow \mu = \frac{1}{|S|} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\rho} \sum_{i \in S} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \right),$$
where $|S|$ is the number of elements in $S$. Then I do not know how to continue. Any comments and answers are welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Break up the sum into each term.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{r} \left[\mu-\frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{r} \mu - \sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i}=1$$

Then you should be able to simplify the first sum, and by factoring out $\frac{1}{\rho}$ from the second sum and rearranging you will get an answer that looks like the one given.

Comment: I don't understand why the $+$ in the subscript can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. Just in second step note that $\sum_{i \in S} (\mu - \frac{1}{p \lambda_i}) = \sum_{i =1} ^{r} (\mu - \frac{1}{p \lambda_i})$ since for any $i \notin S $, $(\mu - \frac{1}{p \lambda_i})_+ = 0$.

Comment: I know for any $i \notin S $, $(\mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i})_+ = 0$. But I don't understand how it results in $\sum_{i \in S} (\mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i}) = \sum_{i =1} ^{r} (\mu - \frac{1}{\rho \lambda_i})$ .